# CustomValidationAttribute doesn't work when other attributes are applied to the class

Tags: validation, .net-4.0, data-annotations, validationattribute

Reproduction:

```
Imports System.ComponentModel
Imports System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations
Module Module1

  Sub Main()
    Dim type = GetType(Contact)
    TypeDescriptor.AddProviderTransparent(
      New AssociatedMetadataTypeTypeDescriptionProvider(type), type)


    Dim contact As New Contact
    Dim context As New ValidationContext(contact, Nothing, Nothing)
    Dim errors As New List(Of ValidationResult)
    Dim result = Validator.TryValidateObject(contact, context, errors, True)
  End Sub
End Module

<CustomValidation(GetType(Contact.ContactMd), "*********************")>
<MetadataType(GetType(Contact.ContactMd))>
Public Class Contact

  Public Property Email As String
  Public Property EmailRepeat As String

  Public Class ContactMd

    '<Required()>
    Public Property Email
    '<Required()>
    Public Property EmailRepeat

    Public Shared Function ValidateEmails(ByVal contact As Contact) _
        As ValidationResult
      Return If(contact.Email = contact.EmailRepeat,
                ValidationResult.Success,
                New ValidationResult("Fail!"))
    End Function
  End Class
End Class
```

The above code will throw an exception:
`The CustomValidationAttribute method '*********************' does not exist in type 'ContactMd' or is not public and static.`

This exception is justified and it's a sign that things are working.
Once I uncomment the `Required` attributes on the properties in the Md class, the exception will not be throw, which means, the validation system doesn't validate for both property-typed attributes and class-level attributes.

Any workaround?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is, that the validation system validates the property validation attributes first (the `Required` attributes in this case), and will only proceed to the `CustomValidationAttribute` if the object passed the property attributes.

So per the reproduction above, changing the line

```
Dim contact As New Contact
```

to something like (allowing the enitity to pass the property validation):

```
Dim contact As New Contact With { .Email = "*", .EmailRepeat = "*" }
```

Will throw the expected exception.

Answer (score 0):

The signature for the method specified by the CustomValidationAttribute must be:

VB:

```
Public Shared Function OnValidate(
    entity As Contact, context As ValidationContext) As ValidationResult
```

C#:

```
public static ValidationResult OnValidate(Contact entity, ValidationContext context)
```

If the validation is OK, it should return ValidationResult.Success.

Comment: I didn't test it, but I am not sure it must be in this signature. The reason the exception is thrown is because its misnamed, otherwise it works fine as far as I remember.